# The egocentric one

Tags: riddle, word

```
Here is the next one for you. I recommend using a list for this.
Oh, almost forgot to tell you that it's freaking easy. Have fun!
```

Even if tiny I call you tall
The first two lines contain no hint at all
For sure I'm egocentric
You mean nothing to me
So the best choice seems a third person to be
Make him steal what surrounds 
<strike>the guy behind the screen</strike> you
Find one more glue
and my full name can be seen

---

If you want to check your answer this might help. The cat in the manger may misuse this as a hint.

> Read on with prudence 
>  and drop the penny
> Some say I'm one, I say I'm many

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a:

> LIST

**EXPLANATION:**

The first two lines contain no hint at all

> This is true.

For sure I'm egocentric
You mean nothing to me

> All things are said from the perspective of the riddle.

So the best choice seems a third person to be

> am, are, **is**

Make him steal what surrounds 
the guy behind the screen

> "you" is the "guy behind the screen". In the preface there is a "you" surrounded with "tel**l** you **t**hat". We take **lt**.
>   
> + *I cal**l** you **t**all*, "freaking easy"

Find one more glue

> We paste what we've got together.

and my full name can be seen

> Indeed

Read on with prudence and drop the penny

> Artistic license.

Some say I'm one, I say I'm many

> A list is actually a collection of items. We refer to a list, but really we refer to the many items of the list. It may also be a play on the similarity of the singular and plural of "list"/"lists".

**IN THE PREFACE:**
"I recommend using a list for this"

> Lynch mob, anyone?

By the way, "List" in German means "Trick" or "Cunning" (avigrail - the author - is German).

Answer (score 1):

I think this fits all clues:

> hacker?

// EDIT

Even if tiny I call you tall
The first two lines contain no hint at all

> well, the above is obvious, first two lines have no hints

For sure I'm egocentric
You mean nothing to me

> blackhat!

So the best choice seems a third person to be

> Man in the middle

Make him steal what surrounds

> Interwebs is everywhere now :-)

the guy behind the screen

> the hacker

Find one more glue
and my full name can be seen

> oh noes, suppose we left a cookie for the feds, we wouldn't be anonymous anymore!

Read on with prudence 
and drop the penny
Some say I'm one, I say I'm many

> anonymous

Comment: You obviously didn't find the last glue!

Comment: Sure I did: 1 hacker or many (like anonymous), or more directly: http://phrack.org/issues/7/3.html#article

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit this answer to explain how you reached this conclusion given the information in the question?

Comment: @Emrakul Done :-) it's been a while though ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'll make a bold guess here :)

Is it

> a server?

*For sure I'm egocentric
You mean nothing to me*

> the server only answers user requests, but usually is not interested in who sent the requests

*So the best choice seems a third person to be*

> the third person might be a browser

*Make him steal what surrounds 
the guy behind the screen*

> the browser can collect some information about the user, for example cookies or http form information

Comment: Good guess. No :)

Comment: On a scale from 1 to 10, where 10 means this is the right answer, how close am I? :)

Answer (score 0):

> Your brain?   or a braincell?

I always act like my brain is another (3th person view) of my world like some spectator haha

Comment: You forgot about the last glue, too!

Answer (score 0):

forgive me if im wrong...

> Cyanoacrylate

For sure I'm egocentric
You mean nothing to me

> An ego centric letter is S which starts the most words in the english dictionary

So the best choice seems a third person to be

> a different perspective or from a different persona leading me to PER also in PERson

Make him steal what surrounds you

> "thought" being deep in thought throughout this riddle which leaves us with U

Find one more glue

> Super Glue which its proper name is Cyanoacrylate

Comment: I forgive you :)

Comment: ahh blasted, I wrote a list an everything :D

Comment: Well, a list is a good thing to start with ;)

Comment: ... techincally i said the answer lol

Comment: Yes you did. I hope you are happy, at least a bit!