# The answer is less complex than the riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> My first is really easy - trust me, it's not hard.
>   Fail here and you will kick yourself.
>   In rhymes it's found with Simon seeking lard;
>   In maths it doesn't meet itself.
>
> My second is found right here on this site:
>   Read on with prudence
>   and drop the penny
>   Some say I'm one, I say I'm many.
>
> My third makes clear you've got it right:
>   A pleasant sight to many students.
>   Or it might be a parasite,
>   Head in deep with every bite.

Put them together, form a whole,
And a single longer word you'll find.
When you've got it, take a stroll
Over [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45927/5373) where clues are combined.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**The first** is surely

> SIMPLE

*My first is really easy - trust me, it's not hard.

Fail here and you will kick yourself.*

> Simple = not hard. If you fail to solve something simple you will be annoyed.

*In rhymes it's found with Simon seeking lard;*

> Simple Simon met a pieman...

*In maths it doesn't meet itself.*

> Simple closed curve.

**The second** is probably

> LIST

*My second is found right here on this site:*

> Lots of lists. List of puzzles, Hot Network Questions, list of users, etc., etc., etc.

*Read on with prudence

and drop the penny*

> This seems like it ought to point to (P)ERUSE or (P)ORE or something, and so far as I know nothing of the kind works ... But see below.

*Some say I'm one, I say I'm many.*

> A list is one thing made up of many things.

So, what about those not-really-fitting lines 2 and 3? Well, the link provided by an anonymous user in comments shows that essentially the same clues have been given for the same answer in another puzzle a couple of years ago, and then those two lines were just filler. I have to say I find this a bit unsatisfactory -- it wasn't fair then, and it isn't fair now -- but never mind :-).

I agree with Mithrandir: **the third** is clearly

> TICK.

**Putting them together** yields

> SIMPLISTIC.

Comment: Does this help with the second part: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/the-egocentric-one/4846#4846

Comment: Well, it helps in that it suggests that the two lines that were puzzling me were just filler, and if I happened to have memorized every puzzle posted here for the last two years I'd have recognized the fact :-). Fair enough, I guess.

Comment: It would've been enough to just put "Read on with prudence
and drop the penny" into the search box :-) Good job on this, and hat tip to @user1566694 for finding the intended meaning of the 2nd verse.

Comment: Well, yes, if I'd guessed that that bit of the clue might be taken verbatim from an old puzzle. That's not a guess I usually make (though I might make it more often in future).

Comment: Can I link your mention of my answer to it?

Comment: Yes, feel free.

Answer (score 4):

### Partial Answer

<s>Second:</s>

> P

My second is found right here on this site:

> **P**uzzling

Read on with prudence

> starts with P

and drop the penny

> Also

Some say I'm one, I say I'm many.

> Could this be a reference to [p orbital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital)?

The third:

> Is probably a tick.

My third makes clear you've got it right:

> Like here - a green check means correct

A pleasant sight to many students.

> I bet it is

Or it might be a parasite,
Head in deep with every bite.

> The bug called a tick